Firewall to allow only web browsing and no other network access
I am working on Debian Stable and it is working very well.
I see apf-firewall to simplify iptables. I want my firewall to only allow web browsing (including forms) and block all other network access. How is this possible with apf-firewall?
Or could I do it with FireHol software? It seems to have simple configuration commands:
version 6

interface4 eth0 home
    server dns   accept
    server ftp   accept
    server samba accept
    server squid accept
    server dhcp  accept
    server http  accept
    server ssh   accept
    server icmp  accept

interface4 ppp+ internet
    server smtp  accept
    server http  accept
    server ftp   accept

Which lines should I keep if I want only web browsing to be permitted?
Edit: Will following 2 rules using nftables be sufficient for my needs?
nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport 80 ct state new,established accept 
nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport 443 ct state new,established accept 


I've skimmed trough the linked document (not in detail) and can't see any advantage over nftables, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Are you going to allow name resolution, too (resolve "foo.org" to 1.2.3.4)? Are you going to allow for software updates? ssh access so it can be maintained?  What are you afraid of? Why won't a standard system work?

@waltinator : I believe standard system (Debian Stable) has no iptables. Is that ok for a general student use? I just want to make a safe system for an average school student who uses network only for web browsing. I do not even know technical details like "name  resolution" and "ssh" (can you believe it!).

@metablaster : I was not aware of nftables. It look much easier than iptables. What would be rule statements in nftables for my needs?

@rnso nftables is advanced and modern firewall for Linux replacing iptables, if you don't know basic things like what DNS or SSH is then I don't know what answer could help you to achieve your objective because it would take a lot of it to explain. so I suggest you to learn step by step, standard start is here: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page

Are rules given on https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_ruleset_for_a_workstation sufficient for my limited need?

Will 2 lines: nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport 80 ct state new,established accept ; plus a similar line for dport 443 be sufficient for my needs?

@mso Before you go any further, you need to understand what a firewall is, and how it relaes to the Internet and general networking.  May I recommend this rather old, but still informative 3D video: Warriors of the Net - Dawn of the Internet.  I know it looks dated but the underlying concepts have not changed in 40 years+

Very interesting introductory video. However, I have a specific question that is still not answered.

For general web browsing, you should not need to accept any incoming connections at all, since everything you'll need are outgoing connections from your system to your DNS resolver server(s) and the various HTTP and HTTPS servers.
Any legitimate incoming packets should then be responses to your outgoing requests only, so any firewall configuration that includes connection tracking can automatically match them up with the outgoing connections they belong to, and automatically accept them.
The two rules you specified:
nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport 80 ct state new,established accept 
nft add rule ip filter input tcp dport 443 ct state new,established accept 

... would allow incoming HTTP and HTTPS connections, so these rules might be applicable in a basic web server.
Likewise, the FireHol configuration you listed is about listing the services running on the firewall host i.e. it assumes FireHol is running on a server system which needs to provide some services to other hosts. On any system that does not provide any services to other systems, you should generally have no server ... accept lines at all.
